# Code not running after os.system call

Tags: python, python-2.7

In this code

```
while 1:
try:
    #print "try reading socket"
    os.system("echo 1 >/sys/class/leds/led0/brightness")

    data, wherefrom = s.recvfrom(1500, 0) # get the data from the socket

except (KeyboardInterrupt, SystemExit):
    #print "reraise error"
    raise
except timeout:
    print "No data received: socket timeout"
    #print sys.exc_info()[0]
    break
except:
    print "Unknown error occured with receiving data"
    break    

print (data + " " + repr(wherefrom[0]))

if (data.find("Start SID" + myserial[-4:]) != -1):

    os.system('sudo python /home/pi/simplesi_scratch_handler/scratch_gpio_handler2.py '+ str(repr(wherefrom[0])))

    for i in range (0,20):
        os.system("echo 0 >/sys/class/leds/led0/brightness")
        time.sleep(0.5)
        os.system("echo 1 >/sys/class/leds/led0/brightness")
        time.sleep(0.5)
    break

os.system("echo mmc0 >/sys/class/leds/led0/trigger")
s.close()
sys.exit()
```

the code after

```
os.system('sudo python /home/pi/simplesi_scratch_handler/scratch_gpio_handler2.py '+ str(repr(wherefrom[0])))
```

doesn't seem to run (the code blinks an LED and this doesn't happen - if I put the blink code befoer the os.system call then it works)

Can I get python to launch a new terminal/shell and run my 2nd python prog in that?

regards

Simon

Comment: It sounds like that particular call is blocking and not returning. Can you verify your scratch_gpio_handler isn't blocking?

Comment: Sudo is likely asking for a password. Try other options or the python pexpect module.

Comment: Thanks for your help - it was a lakc of & at end of command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

modify your sudoers file (with the visudo command) to add this line

```
myusername   ALL=(ALL:ALL) NOPASSWD:/home/pi/simplesi_scratch_handler/scratch_gpio_handler2.py
```

Where "myusername" is the user name that you intend to run the program as

You also mentioned you would like to run the system program in a new shell?

```
os.system('sudo python /home/pi/simplesi_scratch_handler/scratch_gpio_handler2.py '+ str(repr(wherefrom[0])) + " &")
```

runs the program in such a way that the shell it starts does not block the process that starts it.

Hope this helps

Comment: The second suggestion did the job - adding the & - I keep forgetting about that little syntax feature.

Comment: The first one is not needed - its not a password issue :)